# Not able to get password for EC2 instance launched from NVIDIA AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

[image: EC2 Instance AMI Details]

We have requirement to decide on AMI to work with GPU based Virtual Reality Software.
Hence I tried to launch instances from several NVIDIA provided windows based AMIs from Amazon marketplace. Instance is launched & I could see system logs saying instance is ready for use.

However to connect first time with RDP, when I try to get password even after 20 minutes, I see following error message.
[image]

I tried to do work with several AMIs by NVIDIA from Amazon marketplace, however it never worked.

PS: I am able to launch instances & connect with RDP if I launch it with Amazon QuickStart AMIs.

Thanks in advance for any leads on above error.
Also, Is there any alternate way to launch an instance with NVIDIA GPUs & be able to connect with RDP successfully.

Comment: I would like to see review comments from guys downvoting a question. I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days, looking for breakthrough, thanks in advance. Not sure if something wrong with Marketplace AMIs itself.

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally. StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A and many people consider AWS infrastructure questions to be outside the definition of 'programming'.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for your support. However earlier impulsive downvote by someone blocked me from asking question, I hope someday I will recover from block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not figure out why I am not able to decrypt default administrator password, however found alterative solution.

Added following script in user data area as init script that will create new user profile and add to administrator group.

```
<powershell>
net user USERNAME PASSWORD /add /y
net localgroup administrators USERNAME /add
</powershell>
```

After launch of instance I was able to RDP connect and login with USERNAME.